# Probability that the word is of language using N-Grams

Tags: probability-theory

Some programm should allow users to identify the word language probability. All i have is some statistics - the frequency of using `bigrams` and `trigrams` in most of texts of some languages.

Totally i have

`Top English bigrams       Top Spanish bigrams   ...
th                         de                    ...
he                         es                    ...
in                         en                    ...
er                         el                    ...
...                        ...                   ...`

So how can i calculate the probability, that the word is of language?

`

Comment: Do you have a precise definition of "word language probability"? Is it the probability that some word belongs to a language? What do you mean by "the probability, that the word is of language"?

Comment: yes, sorry, probability that some word belongs to a language

Comment: The first step is to come up with a *generative model* for words in a language. This will probably require you to assign probabilities for the bigrams or trigrams.

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/66475/755